# calling TabContainer inside the Updatepanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0

I want to call a Tabcontainer inside the Updatepanel. So there is no need to full refresh or Autopost the Full page just refresh the Updatepanel. But it giving me The Error "Type 'System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel' does not have a public property named 'TabContainer'."

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnltabContainner" runat="server">
   <ajax:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0">
      <ajax:TabPanel ID="panel1" runat="server">
         <ContentTemplate>
           //Contain in the Tabpanel
         </ContentTemplate>
      </ajax:TabPanel>

      <ajax:TabPanel ID="panel2" runat="server">
          <ContentTemplate>
            //Contain in the Tabpanel
          </ContentTemplate>
     </ajax:TabPanel>

  </ajax:TabContainer>

</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Show your code. without your code we cant help you...

Comment: Still interested in a answer ?

Comment: @DatRid thank u sir but i got my ans long ago thank u so much for ur help....

Comment: no problem, just forgot about the answer sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simple.

Inside of an `UpdatePanel`, you also need `<ContentTemplate>`.

So change your code to the following:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnltabContainner" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <ajax:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0">

            <ajax:TabPanel ID="panel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                //Contain in the Tabpanel
                </ContentTemplate>
            </ajax:TabPanel>

            <ajax:TabPanel ID="panel2" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                //Contain in the Tabpanel
                 </ContentTemplate>
            </ajax:TabPanel>

        </ajax:TabContainer>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```